# understanding git patch command (git add -p)

Tags: git

Assume in the original file (numbers.txt) i had,

```
1
2
3
.
4
5
```

once I changed the file (numbers.txt) I get

```
1
2
3
-.
4
5
+6
```

before I stage my changes I want to see which lines I want to accept from the latest edits.

When i run the git patch (git add -p) command, and make the numbers.txt file into, which removes the dot(.) as you can see above.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

now I can commit using (git commit -m 'latest updates')

At this moment I will still have 'numbers.txt' file in my un-staged area. Which is the file with all original patches. But this 'numbers.txt' in un-staged area is not a accurate representation of patches I have accepted in my repository. But my project directory still contains this file.

In future when new patches/changes to (numbers.txt) file come those changes will be compared to the (numbers.txt) in my directory and not the (numbers.txt) that was checkout out.

Question is "How do you guys get rid of this numbers.txt" file and have it updated to the same numbers.txt that was committed?

Comment: Use `git checkout -- numbers.txt` to overwrite the working directory copy of numbers.txt with the copy in the index.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your question is essentially: How can I set the working dir copy of a file to the version in the index. If this is true, I suggest you rewrite your question.

Comment: so basically where ever the head point currently in my git repo, that branch is going to be downloaded into my project directory

Comment: @Micha Wiedenmann please be my guest and edit this question, I tried elaborating it to the best of my abilities

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I am going to answer this question based upon a comment by DietrichEpp

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be,

git checkout -- [FILENAME]

this would make git fetch the file from the checkout (index) into my working directory.

if I want to fetch all the files from the checkout (index) into my working directory I would need to enter,

git checkout -- .

the . at the end would bring in everything from the checkout(index) into my working directory.

This is quiet useful the above two commands when we are accepting file patches.

Because you would get into situation where you will accept a few lines to a FILE and reject some this will put your FILE into staged and un-staged area. You can confirm this by using "git status" command.

Once you commit your FILE, you will not need the version of your file existing inside the un-staged area. For that you would need to use git checkout -- FILENAME command to bring the file from checkout (index) into your working directory.

If you have more than one file patched then it's useful to use *git checkout -- .* command